# Extending goog.Disposable generates jsDoc error

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library, jsdoc

One of my classes generates a jsDoc error because it is extending goog.Disposable. I am using @extends to specify this, but it's still not working. Files compile without errors with the closure linter.
the code can be found here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript file contains the following line:

```js
goog.inherits(goog.Disposable, niuzly.base.errorHandler);
```

***[goog.inherits](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js#1374)*** takes the child constructor followed by the parent constructor:

```js
goog.inherits(niuzly.base.errorHandler, goog.Disposable);
```

For a [JSDoc-Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit) template, you could try [gcodewiki](http://code.google.com/p/gcodewiki/). Using gcodewiki, I successfully generated JSDoc for your file *niuzly.base.errorHandler.js* with the following warnings:

```
>> WARNING: Trying to document errorHandler as a member of undocumented symbol niuzly.base.
>> WARNING: Can't augment contributer: goog.Disposable, not found.
```

Including Closure Library's `base.js` and `disposable.js` as inputs to JSDoc-Toolkit eliminates the warning `Can't augment contributer: goog.Disposable, not found.`

To eliminate the warning about the undocumented symbol `niuzly.base`, you could add the following to your source file or just ignore the warning.

```js
/**
 * @type {Object} Namespace for Niuzly Inc.
 */
var niuzly = niuzly || {};

/**
 * @type {Object} Base namespace.
 */
niuzly.base = niuzly.base || {};
```

## [JSDoc 3](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc)

Using [JSDoc 3](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) instead of the older JSDoc-Toolkit successfully generated documentation when only *niuzly.base.errorHandler.js* and *disposable.js* were specified. In addition, there was no warning about the undocumented symbol `niuzly.base`.

Comment: JSDoc 3 appears to be more forgiving (and easier to use) than JSDoc-Toolkit. See updated answer.